# "Version specific synonyms can only be created by moderators"?

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

I was trying to create a synonym of [64-bit](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/64-bit) to amasse all the questions that are related about the cpu architecture and the interaction with the installation and execution of programs in Ubuntu, but got denied with the following message:

[image]

I have enough knowledge about what is the tag about and how to improve it, so I don't know why I would need a mod (after all, is difficult to propose a tag merge/synonym since most of the time no user has the "points") to propose a synonym.

Comment: I think you're running into the software trying to stop versioned tags like "tomcat6" and "php4".

Comment: @JorgeCastro *facedesk*